# Problema na busca utilizando o queryset do Django na hora de editar

Tags: python, django

Fico grado pela ajuda, pois não estou conseguindo realizar essa busca,
mesmo realizando a busca, me retorna o id certo (id_setor e id_empresa) porém o Django não reconhece ou estou fazendo algo errado.

**Erro "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing"**

**Views**

```py
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def ed_ramal(request):
    id_ramal = request.GET.get('id')
    id_setor = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('setor_ramais')
    id_empresa = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('empresa_ramais')

    if id_ramal:
        ed_ramal = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('ramal')
        i_resp = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('nome_resp')
        i_mail = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('email')
        setor = Setores.objects.filter(id=id_setor[0]['setor_ramais'])
        empresa= Empresas.objects.filter(id=id_empresa[0]['empresa_ramais'])
        dados = {'ramal': ed_ramal, 'responsavel': i_resp, 'email': i_mail, 'setores': setor, 'empresas': empresa}
    else:
        empresa = Empresas.objects.all()
        setor = Setores.objects.all()
        dados = {'empresas': empresa, 'setores': setor}
    return render(request, 'ramal.html', dados)
```

**Models**

```
    class Ramais(models.Model):
        ramal = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='Ramal')
        nome_resp = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Responsavél')
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
        setor_ramais = models.ForeignKey(Setores, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Setor')
        empresa_ramais = models.ForeignKey(Empresas,on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Empresa')
        data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


        class Meta:
            db_table = 'ramais'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.ramal + str(self.setor_ramais)+ str(self.empresa_ramais)
```

Código Html antes de editar:

```
{% extends "parciais/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <nav class="navbar center">
           <form class="form-inline" method="GET">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 "type="text" name="search" id="buscar">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Consulta</button>
           </form>
       </nav>
            <section id="lista_ramais">
                <div class="container-fluid lista_ramais">
                    <p>LISTA DE RAMAIS</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        <section class="container-fluid margin">
            <div class="table-responsive-lg">
                <table class="table table-xl table-striped">
                    <thead class="claro" align="center">
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col">RAMAL</th>
                        <th scope="col">RESPONSAVÉL</th>
                        <th scope="col">SETOR</th>
                        <th scope="col">EMPRESA</th>
                        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                            <th scope="col">EDIÇÃO
                              <a href="edicao/">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">ADICIONAR</button>
                              </a>
                            </th>
                        {% endif %}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                           {% for i in ramais %}
                                <tr>
                                <th>{{i.ramal}}</th>
                                <td>{{ i.nome_resp | upper }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.setor_ramais | upper }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.empresa_ramais }}</td>
                                {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                                     <td>
                                        <a href="edicao/?id={{ i.id }}">
                                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">EDITAR</button>
                                        <!/a>
                                         <a href="/delete/{{ i.id }}">
                                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">EXCLUIR</button>
                                        </a>
                                     </td>
                                {% endif %}
                                </tr>
                           {% endfor %}
                      </tbody>
                </table>
                <nav aria-label="Navegação de página exemplo">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                      {% for pagina in ramais.paginator.page_range %}
                        {% if ramais.number == pagina %}
                            <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ pagina }}">{{ pagina }}</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                           <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ pagina }}">{{ pagina }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div align="right">
                <button type="button" onclick="window.print()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Imprimir</button>
            </div>
        </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Codigo HTML de edição / adicionar

```
{% extends "parciais/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" >
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static '/style.css' %}" >

<section>
    <div class="container w-auto lista">
        <p>RAMAL</p>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container w-auto bgcolor_cad">
        <form action="submit" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
         <input type="number" name="id_ramal" value="{{ i.id }}">
           <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                  <label>Ramal:</label>
                  <input type="number" name="ramal" class="form-control" value="{{ i.ramal  }}"  >
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-4">
                  <label>Responsável:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="responsavel"  class="form-control" value="{{ i.nome_resp }}" >
                </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" value="{{ i.emal }}">
                  </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label >Setor:</label>
                      <select id="inputState" name="setor" class="form-control">
                        {% for s in setores %}
                            <option  value="{{ s.id }}" name="pk_setor">{{ s.setor }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                        <a href="/ramais/edicao/setor/">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">ADICIONAR</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputState">Empresa:</label>
                      <select id="inputState01" name="empresa"  class="form-control">
                        {% for e in empresas %}
                            <option  value="{{ e.id }}" name="pk_empresa">{{ e.nome_emp }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SALVAR</button>
            <a href="/ramais/">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CANCELAR</button>
            </a>
        </form>
</section>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Código completo no meu GitHub: https://github.com/cristianpaes/RAMAIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com o filter obténs um queryset, logo o resultado não é id, para id_sector e id_empresa, utiliza algo assim:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
    def ed_ramal(request):

        id_ramal = request.GET.get('id')
        id_setor = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('setor_ramais')
        id_empresa = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('empresa_ramais')

        if id_ramal:
            ramal = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal)
            setor = Setores.objects.filter(id=id_setor[0]['setor_ramais'])
            empresa= Empresas.objects.filter(id=id_empresa[0]['empresa_ramais'])
            dados = {'empresas': empresa, 'setores': setor, 'ramal':ramal}

        else:
            empresa = Empresas.objects.all()
            setor = Setores.objects.all()
            dados = {'empresas': empresa, 'setores': setor}
        return render(request, 'ramal.html', dados)
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração que informou, porém ainda continua dando erro de tipo. TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got {'setor_ramais': 1}.

Comment: Fix a correção, valida agora.

Comment: Agora deu outro erro: 'Setores' object is not iterable.

Comment: Agora deduzo que tenhas outro problema no html ao iterar os 'setores', estas a ver aquele HTML, **que não partilhaste**. Não podem esperar ajuda sem partilham aqui o código.

Comment: Coloquei o HTML onde pego o ID e tem meu github, para verificar todos os html e codigos completos. Só não consigo resolver isso.

Comment: Corrigi no código que partilhei, no teu HTML não tem problema, mas sim na função **ed_ramal**, como não tinha acesso a esse código não podia perceber como apresentas no template. Qual aqui o problema, não podes passar para um for loop no template uma e uma só instancia do Objeto Setores ou Empresas, (este último iria dar erro a serguir após corrigir o de Setores), é o que acontece ao fazer *.objects.get(), tens de utilizar o *.filter(), desta forma o ORM de Django retorna um QuerySet desse objeto e iterável, mesmo sendo só um, não sei se é este o objetivo com o if id_ramal:. ter um dropdown.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou e era coisa boba. Estou aprendendo e acontece isso.

Comment: Pode me ajudar, a trazer os valores do Ramal, responsável e email. E teria como deixar interativo o setores e Empresa? a minha ideia seria trocar caso a pessoa seja transferida.

Comment: Penso que deverias fechar esta questão, e abrir nova, a tua dúvida aqui ficou resolvida. Coloca o código e detalha muito bem o problema, "a minha ideia seria trocar caso a pessoa seja transferida", só isto não chega. Tenta ser o mais objetivo possível.